# Limit by L´Hopital

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have to calculate the following limit :

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{x-1}}{(x-1)^x}  $$

I try it taking logarithm and exponential: $$\frac{e^{(x-1)\log(x)}}{e^{x\log(x-1)}}, $$ but I still can't solve it.

Comment: How about writing the function as $\left(1+\frac1{x-1}\right)^x\cdot \frac1x$ then use fundamental limits?

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\lim_{x \to +\infty}\left( 1-\frac{1}{x} \right) ^x=\color{red}{\frac{1}{e}}$.

However, $\frac{x^{x-1}}{(x-1)^x}=\frac{x^{x-1}}{\left[ x(1-\frac{1}{x}) \right]^x}=\frac{x^{x-1}}{x^x(1-\frac{1}{x})^x}=\frac{1}{x(1-\frac{1}{x})^x}$.

The requested limit is therefore $0$.

Comment: Actually $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=\frac{1}{e}$, but the argument works either way

Comment: @Lorago :  :) thanks. I'll correct.